# How to test Multitasking in TinyOS?

Tags: tinyos

I want to see the FCFS scheduling of TinyOS. But not getting how to provide multiple tasks and what type of multiple tasks can be provided to test scheduling in TinyOS.

Answer (score 0):

TinyOS (via nesC) provides the `task` and `post` keywords to allow you to queue functions to be performed later by the scheduler. A good starting point is the [Tutorial on Modules and the TinyOS Execution Model](http://tinyos.stanford.edu/tinyos-wiki/index.php/Modules_and_the_TinyOS_Execution_Model). As noted there, TEP 106 (see under the `doc` directory of your TinyOS install) provides more detail on the scheduler.